# Embedded flashplayer

Tags: flash

I'm looking for an easy, clean flashplayer to embed videos to my website. I came a cross some players searching via Google and JW Player (Longtail) has my very interest but it comes with a, small, price.

Do you guys know any equivalent players for playing swf files which are free and can be used commercial?

Comment: JW Player (Open Source) is free.

Comment: But not if you are using it for commercial purposes, the website Im intending to use it for has a 'little' commercial smell ;)

Comment: Isn't Adobe's official Flash Player free to use in web sites?  I am under the impression that they charge for their content generation tools, but not the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [osflv](http://www.osflv.com/). GPL, no usage-situation restrictions.